# Parent/Closest Div Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT:
I have the following code:

```
<div class="specificBlock" id="thevagabond">
     <a class="intro"><img src="images/blabla.png"/></a> 
     </br>
     <div class="btn-group-xs testing">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success intro">Use</a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="specificBlock" id="thedog">
     <a class="intro"><img src="images/blabla.png"/></a> 
     </br>
     <div class="btn-group-xs testing">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success intro">Use</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

My issue is the following:
I'd like to find a jQuery/JavaScript way to get the ID of the div from which the clicked 'a' class="intro" comes from.

The problem here is that if the first `a` with `class="intro"` is clicked on, I would need to use the closest div's ID.

But if I click on the second the closest div is not the right one - the closest would be then the div with `class="testing"`, which I don't want.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why to use closest? You need div with id just use `$("#thevagabond")`

Comment: You can pass selectors to closest: https://api.jquery.com/closest/. But I second AJ's question too.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. I wasn't clear enough with my problem. Can you give it a look right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID should be unique, so you would do just `$('#thevagabond')`. However, you probably need to use `.parents(selector_here)` - check [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

If you really need ID, check this:

```
$('.specificBlock a').click(function(){
var id_that_you_looking_for = $(this).parents('.specificBlock').attr('id');
//code more
});
```

Comment: Actually I'll have other blocks exactly like this. The only thing that's gonna change is the ID.
That's why there is a problem.

Should have mentionned that sorry :)

Comment: Check my edited answer. Also consider to use data attributes in HTML. Link could be looks like `<a data-url_to_load="http:\\xxx" type="button" class="btn btn-success intro">Use</a>`

Comment: Thanks. I think I got my answer.
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  $(this).parents("#thevagabond");
});
```

or as mentioned before `#thevagabond` directly.

**EDIT:**
Depending on the new information (see comments below) heres a new solution.
You could either place the target URL for the `iframe` in the `href`of the `a` or add an `data-`attribute to either the `a` or one of its parents.

HTML:

```
<div class="specificBlock" id="thevagabond" data-url="my/iframe/url">
     <a class="intro"><img src="images/blabla.png"/></a> 
     </br>
     <div class="btn-group-xs testing">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success intro">Use</a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="specificBlock" id="thedog">
     <a class="intro" href="my/iframe/url"><img src="images/blabla.png"/></a> 
     </br>
     <div class="btn-group-xs testing">
        <a type="button" href="my/iframe/url" class="btn btn-success intro">Use</a>
     </div>
</div>

<iframe id="my-frame" src="" width="500" height="500" style="display:none" />
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var $specificBlocks = $(".specificBlock"),
    $thevagabond = $specificBlocks.filter("#thevagabond"),
    $thedog = $specificBlocks.filter("#thedog"),
    $iframe = $("#my-frame");

$thevagabond.on("click", "a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $iframe.attr("src", $thevagabond.data("url"));
  $iframe.show();
});

$thedog.on("click", "a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $t = $(this),
      url = $t.attr("href");

  $iframe.attr("src", url);
  $iframe.show();
});
```

I would prefer the `#thedog` option because the page that will be shown in the iframe will be also accessable for non JS users and search engines.

Comment: Actually I'll have other blocks exactly like this. The only thing that's gonna change is the ID.
That's why there is a problem.

Should have mentionned that sorry :)

Comment: You mean the code repeats with diffrent IDs? If so, then just use a class and it will work fine.

Comment: Yes but I need to get the IDs because I will then display an iframe src different depending on the ID from which the clicked a comes from...

Comment: Let's say my iframe is <iframe src=""> so far.
I'd like to fill in the src depending on the ID from which the clicked a comes from

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.
That helps a lot!